# How to check Livewire event is completed

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have 3 components Map, Field & Section. Map is the parent component. Field & Section are child components.

There is an action called `testField` in Field component. Inside the `test` function first I want to trigger an event `SaveSection` on Section component and then continue other stuff.

```
// In field component
public function testField(): void
{
    // Save section
    $this->emitTo('section', 'saveSection');
    Log::debug('Testing.....');

}

// In section component
public function saveSection()
{
    Log::debug('saveSection+++++');
    $this->emitTo('map', 'storeSection', $this->section, $this->sectionIndex);
}


// In map component
public function storeSection(array $section, int $sectionIndex)
{
    Log::debug('storeSection-----');
    // Store to DB
    ....
}
```

But it prints `Testing.....` before `storeSection-----`. Is there way I can wait for events to finish before continue.

Comment: Are you emitting livewire events and attempting to detect when the events are processed?

Comment: @mrtorks Yes something like that. I want to do the testing after the data has been saved.

Answer (score 1):

Hi based on our conversation, I think you would want to go with hooking into Livewire and listening for message processed events.
The first step would be to wrap `Log::debug('Testing.....');` in a function like this. The original idea came from **@Prospero** [Livewire show loader when an event is emitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442517/3889252)

```
public function testLog()
{
  Log::debug('Testing.....');
}
```

You might want to tweak this to your satisfaction as this is just a recommendation.

Now you need to prepare your application to stack scripts in the base view right before the closing body tag. eg in `app.blade.php` like this

```
<body>
 ...//Whatever thats before it
  @stack('scripts')
</body>
```

This would help you stack the custom script tag you would define in the component view.
After this you now use the Livewire hook. Do this properly to avoid DOM diffing issues as Livewire would cry tears in your developer console:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
 Livewire.hook("message.processed", (message, component) => {
if (message.updateQueue[0].payload.event === "storeSection") {
// I have not implemented it this way so try any of them
//@this is a brilliant decorator that finds the component
            @this.emit('testLog') or @this.call('testLog')
        }
    });
 })
</script>
```

This would show ``` Testing....`` after ``` storeSection``` is processed.
Please do let me know if this does not work as I might have to implement changes.

Comment: Looks like a solution, but I'm not able to make it work. I added a console log before the if condition & inside the if condition and it is not printing.

Comment: Hi @SauminiNavaratnam Could you create a small project replicating this so I take look. Thats is if you are comfortable.